# Issue with Configuring OpenAM Agent

Tags: tomcat, openam

I have an openam agent (jee agent v5.6.0) deployed on Tomcat container. When I am trying to access the below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.forgerock.agents.exceptions.FatalConfigurationException: Agent failed to log in with username amadmin and realm /
com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.getLocalOrRemoteProperties(AgentConfiguration.java:927)
com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.firstTimeConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:1521)
com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.initialise(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:206)
com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.doFilter(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:74)
```

I have added the agent in my opem am server as below:

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agent.logout.url[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agenturi.prefix=http://XXXXXXXX:8080/amagent
com.sun.identity.agents.config.anonymous.user.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.anonymous.user.id=anonymous
com.sun.identity.agents.config.attribute.multi.value.separator=|
com.sun.identity.agents.config.audit.accesstype=LOG_NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.auth.connection.timeout=2
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url[0]=https://sso-openam-dev.XXXXX.com:443/openam/cdcservlet
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cookie.domain[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.change.notification.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cleanup.interval=30
com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.ip.validation.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.convert.mbyte.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.name=iPlanetDirectoryPro
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.secure=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file.rotate=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file.size=10000000
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.level=Error
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.check.name.database=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.config.name=LtpaToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.cookie.name=LtpaToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.encode.cookie.special.chars.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.encode.url.special.chars.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fetch.from.root.resource=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.check.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.default=XXXXXX.com
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.get.client.host.name=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info.for.not.enforced.list=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.preferred.naming.url=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.server.check=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.filter.priority=HIGH
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.logonuser=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable.change.protocol=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.password.header=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.load.balancer.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.rotate=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.size=52428800
com.sun.identity.agents.config.locale=en_US
com.sun.identity.agents.config.log.disposition=REMOTE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0]=https://sso-openam-dev.XXXXXXXX.com:443/openam/UI/Login
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.cookie.reset[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url[0]=https://sso-openam-dev.XXXXXXXX.com:443/openam/UI/Logout
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url.attributes.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url.invert=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notification.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.host=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.notification.url=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.port=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.protocol=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.cache.polling.interval=3
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.clock.skew=0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.poll.primary.server=5
com.sun.identity.agents.config.polling.interval=60
com.sun.identity.agents.config.postcache.entry.lifetime=10
com.sun.identity.agents.config.postdata.preserve.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.cookie.maxage=300
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.cookie.prefix=HTTP_
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.fetch.mode=NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.proxy.override.host.port=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.redirect.param=goto
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.log.interval=5
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.logfile=amAgent_XXXXXXXX.log
com.sun.identity.agents.config.repository.location=centralized
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.fetch.mode=NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.fetch.mode=NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.sso.cache.polling.interval=3
com.sun.identity.agents.config.sso.only=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.url.comparison.case.ignore=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param=UserToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param.type=session
com.sun.identity.client.notification.url=http://XXXXXXX:8080/UpdateAgentCacheServlet?shortcircuit=false
org.forgerock.openam.agents.config.policy.evaluation.application=iPlanetAMWebAgentService
org.forgerock.openam.agents.config.policy.evaluation.realm=/
sunIdentityServerDeviceKeyValue[0]=agentRootURL=http://XXXXXXX:8080/
sunIdentityServerDeviceStatus=Active
userpassword=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have properly connected to the openam server. However I am not sure why this error is coming. Is there anything I am missing? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `amadmin` to authenticate the agent?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.forgerock.agents.exceptions.FatalConfigurationException: Agent failed to log in with username amadmin and realm /
```

In agent bootstrap file you have to configure the agent profile name. The agent uses those credentials to authenticate against AM and to retrieve the central profile (if configured).